# Determining .net framework version in a running application

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, version, .net-assembly

(edited)
Why does AssemblyName.Version report the same version even when I change the target version of my project?  How can I determine the actual executing version of the framework?

This always returns 4.0.0.0

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var aName = assembly.GetName();
            Console.WriteLine($"{aName.Name} {aName.Version}" );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Official example from Microsoft to detect .NET Framework runtime version is as below,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_d

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public class GetDotNetVersion
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      GetDotNetVersion.Get45PlusFromRegistry();
   }

   private static void Get45PlusFromRegistry()
   {
      const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";

    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
      {
        if (ndpKey != null && ndpKey.GetValue("Release") != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version: " + CheckFor45PlusVersion((int) ndpKey.GetValue("Release")));
        }
         else {
            Console.WriteLine(".NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.");
         } 
    }
   }

   // Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility.
   private static string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
   {
      if (releaseKey >= 461808)
         return "4.7.2 or later";
      if (releaseKey >= 461308)
         return "4.7.1";
      if (releaseKey >= 460798)
         return "4.7";
      if (releaseKey >= 394802)
         return "4.6.2";
      if (releaseKey >= 394254)
         return "4.6.1";      
      if (releaseKey >= 393295)
         return "4.6";      
      if (releaseKey >= 379893)
         return "4.5.2";      
      if (releaseKey >= 378675)
         return "4.5.1";      
      if (releaseKey >= 378389)
       return "4.5";      
    // This code should never execute. A non-null release key should mean
    // that 4.5 or later is installed.
    return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
   }
}   
// This example displays output like the following:
//       .NET Framework Version: 4.6.1
```

**Update:**
Turn out the true issue is related to the default set of SSL/TLS protocols that's used by .NET Framework classes, where if your assemblies are compiled against a certain framework version at compile time would trigger different runtime behaviors.

The AppContext switch is `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=true"/>` as documented in KB3069494,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3069494/cannot-connect-to-a-server-by-using-the-servicepointmanager-or-sslstre

You might also check the best practice article for more tips,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: This does not answer the question I am asking.  This answers the question of "which versions are installed?"  I am asking the question "which version is the current application using?  Note the italics in the first sentence of my posting.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn your application can only use the installed .NET Framework version (simply because .NET Framework 4.x uses in-place upgrade). That's the so called runtime version. If you are asking for other version numbers, edit your question again please.

Comment: then how does it happen that (other parts of ) my application produce different results when I target a different framework version and run it on the the same machine?   As noted, I change the target from 4.5 to 4.6 and get different behavior.

Comment: Well, that's your real question. Microsoft designed compatibility layers to pretend that your apps running on an older .NET Framework version, which is well known if you check documentation like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#whats-new-in-net-2015 ("Compatibility switches" section). Depending on what exactly differences in behavior you observed, there are ways to address them accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I see that my original question was poorly informed.  I'll accept your answer.  It could be helpful to others if you could edit it to begin by saying something like "Many .net versions are in-place upgrades, where  the assembly continues to report the original version value.  To determine the actual version, read the registry, as shown in the following code. "  (correct?)    Regarding my real problem, it's that  a WebRequest fails when tls 1.2 is required, and when targeting fw < 4.6 vs. 4.6,  running on 4.7.1   I haven't' found a relevant compatibility switch but still looking. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to edit the answer in some way before I can upvote it.

Comment: I think I found the switch so just updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174373/discussion-between-elroy-flynn-and-lex-li).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private static string GetExecutingAssemblyTargetFramework()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute targetFrameworkAttribute = asm.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault()
            as System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute;
        if (targetFrameworkAttribute != null)
            result = targetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkDisplayName;
        return result;
    }
```

You can also use the same loop from the original question:

```
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetAssemblyTargetFramework(assembly));
        }

   private static string GetAssemblyTargetFramework(System.Reflection.Assembly asm)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute targetFrameworkAttribute = asm.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault()
            as System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute;
        if (targetFrameworkAttribute != null)
            result = targetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkDisplayName;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: OP isn't looking for the TargetFramework, he's looking for the currently executing framework versions.  Target framework is an indicator of which framework the assembly was built against, not what framework is currenting executing the assembly.